# NodaTime Instant changing when saved to DB with EF?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, nodatime

I have a .NET Core web app I'm working on and have noticed a strange issue that only occurs on my local instance. For one of our models, we get the start time in UTC. Here is the value from the debugger when db.Add(...) is called:

[image: 2022-11-04T20:00:00Z]

However, the value changes once inside the database. Here is the value once inside the DB:

[image: 2022-11-05T02:00:00Z]

For context, we have a QA and production environment (along with a 2 other developer isntances) with the same code that doesn't have this issue. I am in MST (0600 from UTC), so it appears the input StartTime is treated as an MST instead of UTC datetime.

To me this points to a difference with the Postgres config, but that has its TimeZone set to UTC as well... Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Comment: What data type StartTime has?

Comment: It's a timestamp with time zone in the DB, NodaTime Instant in the app

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

For anyone who stumbles across this issue, this was because of my Postgresql `timezone` parameter was set to my local MST time zone. You can find this in postgresql.conf (On Windows it's `Program Files/PostgreSQL/<version>/data/postgresql.conf`) and change it to `GMT` to fix this issue.

**More Info**

I had originally checked this inside my IDE's (Rider) DB console, but it was actually showing as UTC. I believe this was because my IDE was setting the timezone to UTC as a session variable. Helpful in most cases, but obfuscated the issue I was having.

Suprise suprise, the answer came from the [documentation for timestamp with timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) that specified if no timezone is found, it assumes the timestamp is in the timezone from the psql parameters, converts it to UTC, and stores it.